# Facebook SDK: invalid href when referencing pic in post

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

When using below code to post, I get the following message:

> (OAuthException) (#100) One or more of your image records failed to include a valid 'href' field.

If I clear the picture string, it posts fine...Any thoughts?

```
string picture = "http://www.myserver.com/FBImage/FBUSERID-Large.png";

var client = new FacebookClient(tokenCode);
        FacebookPost fbp = new FacebookPost();
        fbp.message = message;
        fbp.link = link;
        fbp.picture = picture.Trim(); 
        fbp.name = name;  
        fbp.caption = caption;
        fbp.description = description;

        dynamic result = client.Post("me/feed", fbp);
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Please provide background information on the SDK you are using.  Your "picture" is clearly not a valid **href** field.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, solved by removing 'http://' from the picture field

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a `href` field while sending the image. Look for an `href` property for `FacebookPost` object. The SDK I use uses a JSON object to pass all those data and whenever I forget to include the href property, it gives me the same error.